# Is domContentLoaded event fired before request for images is fired?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

Is there a dom event that fires once dom is loaded but no requests have been fired.

As far i know images are loaded async. And as soon as dom parser encounters the image tag it fires of the request for image resources.

so parsing goes something like this:

request html -> parsing html as it comes -> encounter css tag -> request css -> parsing html (into nodes) as it comes -> waiting for all css to finish downloading and parsed -> find img tag so fire request for image -> get more html parse it -> css is complete start dom tree and rendering -> get more html add dom elements -> get image render image too.

As it can be seen images get fired as soon as they are encountered in html while parsing it, even if whole html hasn't been received or parsed let alone converted to nodes.

The reason i want to manipulate image tags is that i want them to not send request for jpg and instead webp if possible.

Modernizr http://www.stucox.com/blog/using-webp-with-modernizr/ way requires dom to be constructed and THEN once webp has been detected start images request which i think can be bad for critical rendering path or at least user experience. We are just delaying loading of resources for the sake of loading smaller resources so it takes less time, but we are increasing time by waiting for it.

Right now only way i think is best to use webp is using server side solution where you can check accept header. Otherwise, other solutions seems like more work at negative value.

Comment: _DOMContentLoaded_ fires after the `.html` file has been parsed into the _DOM_. Any external references may have already begun to load in before the `.html` file has finished parsing. This means you cannot guarantee _DOMContentLoaded_ will fire before any other requests. As you seem to have server-side control, why not use _JSON_ to load in your link source data, then _JavaScript_ to append the images in the desired fashion?

Comment: thats a good solution to load correct format of images, but it also means i'd be wasting bandwidth of network by not loading images async as would have if parser had encounter them while parsing.

Comment: sorry I think you misunderstand, instead of sending `<img src="foo" /><img src="bar"/><img src="baz"/>` send `var images = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]` (where this _Array_ is generated by some _JSON method_ on your server) then on _load_, do `for (let i = 0; i < images.length; ++i) /*do whatever with images[i] */`

Comment: doesn't js run after cssom is constructed, which means it'd be after css is loaded parsed and applied to dom.